# where is the suitable page to place the clickable listView code

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

First of all, i would like to inform that i'm creating an android application that allow user to view and register contact by using sqlite to store data 
And also, i use AsyncTask for performing insert and view data.
Now, i wonder about where should i write the clickable viewlist code. 
It should write in the backgroudTask or in the displaycontact page?
Can somebody provide me some example how to implant it?
Here is the example code and some explanation.
This is the backgoundTask.

```
package com.example.assignment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask <String ,Contact, String> {

    Context ctx;
    ContactAdapter contactAdapter;
    Activity activity;
    ListView listView;
    BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
        activity = (Activity)ctx;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Contact... values) {
        contactAdapter.add(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String method = params[0];
        DatabaseOperations databaseOperations = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);
        if (method.equals("add_info")){

            String cFamName  = params[1];
            String cFirName  = params[2];
            String cHouseNo   = params[3];
            String cStreet   = params[4];
            String cTown     = params[5];
            String cCountry  = params[6];
            String cPostcode = params[7];
            String cTelNo    = params[8];
            SQLiteDatabase db = databaseOperations.getWritableDatabase();
            databaseOperations.putInformation(db ,cFamName,cFirName,cHouseNo,cStreet,cTown,cCountry,cPostcode,cTelNo);
            return "One Row Inserted...";
        }
        else if(method.equals("get_info")){
            listView = (ListView)activity.findViewById(R.id.display_listview);
            SQLiteDatabase db = databaseOperations.getReadableDatabase(); 
                Cursor cursor = databaseOperations.getInformations(db);
                contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(ctx, R.layout.display_contact_row);
                String cFamName, cFirName, cTelNo;
                while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                    cFamName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.eeFamName));
                    cFirName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.eeFirName));
                    cTelNo   = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.eeTelNo));
                    Contact contact  = new Contact(cFamName, cFirName, cTelNo);
                    publishProgress(contact);
                }
                return "get_info";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.equals("get_info")){
            listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }       
    }
}
```

And here is the DisplayContact code that display contact called the backgroudTask to shows the list.

```
package com.example.assignment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class DisplayContact extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_contact);
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute("get_info");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_contact, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is the my contactAdaper

```
package com.example.assignment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    List<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    public ContactAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void add(Contact object){
        list.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
        public Object getItem(int position){
            return list.get(position);
        }

    @Override
    public  View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row = convertView;
        ContactHolder contactHolder;
        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.display_contact_row,parent,false);
            contactHolder = new ContactHolder();
            contactHolder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            contactHolder.number = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.number);
            row.setTag(contactHolder); 
        }
        else{
            contactHolder = (ContactHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Contact contact  = (Contact)getItem(position);
        contactHolder.name.setText(contact.getName().toString());
        contactHolder.number.setText(contact.getTelNo().toString());
    return row;
    }

    static class ContactHolder{
        TextView name, number;
    }

}
```

Comment: A Click is a part of the UI, so it should be in your Activity/Fragment implementing the listener or a seperate listener attached to it. I think your problem is that you are trying to create the UI onResponse. better way is to create the UI directly and just fill in the data recieved by the asyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you need that code.

If you need it only in one activity/fragment, put it in that activity/fragment. If you need it into many areas, the best way is to implement a function on the object you duplicate (fragment ? custom object ? task ?) and call that function with proper parameters when on click is performed.

For example, you could have your asyncTask extending "OnClickListener", and use `button.setOnClickListener(asyncTask);`.
If you need more parameters, you could have a function in your asyncTask like "doOnClick(View view, param1, param2 ...)" then using anonymous onClickListener :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        asyncTask.doOnClick(view, param1, param2, ...);
    }
});
```

Your first step is to understand what you want : local code ? reusable one ?... then implement the function on what will be replicated (or in the activity).